# chrome devtool network reveal react js code even before login happens

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when a user comes to my website the logging page appears.

if the user opens developer tools and goto the network section and then opens **main.chunk.js** file then he is able to see the whole code that I write when the user logged in.

so, this is a security issue on my website  (my API URL, name, params are reveals).

I didn't know how can I secure my website for this vulnerability.

*My login and other routes are in the same file*

Please give me the best practice that prevents this issue.